# ¿Porque tengo un error "too much recursion" al intentar hacer un submit() con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

Estoy intentando hacer un simple submit() a través de JavaScript pero en la consola me sale un error de "too much recursion" y ahí se frena el programa.

Estoy intentando de validar los clicks dentro de un modal y guardar los input's clickeados en un arreglo, si luego el arreglo cumple con ciertas condiciones se hace el submit, sino sale un mensaje de error para el usuario.

```
/* Validar checkboxes clickeados */
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.single-checkbox');
var clickeados = [];

checkboxes.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if(elem.checked) {
           if(!clickeados.includes(elem)){
                   clickeados.push(elem);
                   console.log(clickeados);
           }
        }
        else{
            if(clickeados.includes(elem)){
                   clickeados.pop(elem);
                   console.log(clickeados);
            }
        }
    });
});

/* Validar cuantos gustos fueron seleccionados antes de hacer el submit */
$('#vasitoForm').on('submit', (event) =>
    if(clickeados.length == 0){
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("errorGustos").innerHTML = "Debe seleccionar por lo menos un gusto";
    }
    else if(clickeados.length > 0 && clickeados.length < 3){
        $('#vasitoForm').submit();
    }
});
```

El preventDefault() anda bien si no se clickea nada y muestra el mensaje de error sin redirigir, pero al tener input's clickeados y hacer el submit() me sale por consola el mensaje de "too much recursion" !

El HTML es el siguiente:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="vasoModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Vasito</h4>
        <h6>Seleccione hasta dos gustos</h6>
        <form th:action="@{/pedido}" id="vasitoForm" method="post">
            <table class="tabla">
                    <tr th:each="gusto : ${gustos}">
                        <td class="flavour" th:text="${gusto.nombre}"></td>
                        <td><input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" th:value="${gusto.id}"/></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            <p id="errorGustos"></p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar Pedido</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alguna idea de porque pasa esto y de como se puede solucionar ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Te analizo el código para que veas el problema:

Este código es equivalente al tuyo, pero damos un nombre a la función a ejecutar:

```
// Pongamos un nombre a la función
const callbackFunction = (event) =>
    if(clickeados.length == 0){
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("errorGustos").innerHTML = "Debe seleccionar por lo menos un gusto";
    }
    else if(clickeados.length > 0 && clickeados.length < 3){
        $('#vasitoForm').submit(); // ESTE ES EL PROBLEMA
    }
}

$('#vasitoForm').on('submit', callbackFunction);
```

Por tanto:

1. Asignas al evento `submit` la ejecución de `callbackFunction`.
2. El usuario hace un `submit`
3. Ha ocurrido el evento submit! Se llama a `callbackFunction`.
4. La función `callbackFunction` cancela el evento actual con `event.preventDefault();`.
5. La función `callbackFunction` comprueba que todo está bien y se puede hacer el submit, por lo tanto llama a `form.submit()`, que lanza el evento `submit`. **GO TO 3**

Entras en un bucle en el que el evento submit se para y se lanza un nuevo evento igual. Es un bucle de recursión indirecta sin caso base, luego no termina nunca y el intérprete de JS acaba sin memoria, provocando el fallo.

La solución es la siguiente:

```
const callbackFunction = (event) =>
  if(clickeados.length > 0 && clickeados.length < 3) {
     return; // todo va bien, dejamos que todo siga, hemos terminado
  }
  // algo no está bien, cancelamos el evento
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("errorGustos").innerHTML = "Debe seleccionar por lo menos un gusto";

}

$('#vasitoForm').on('submit', callbackFunction);
```